# how can i solve this situation in centos(linux) to run ASP.net-mvc?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website project deveolped with entity framework(.net+razor+mvc4) and linq.it work fun in windows server.now i have to transfer the project into centos(linux) server(mono+apache).There is an error like title,and detail below:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Data.
>
> Exception stack trace:
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory (System.String providerInvariantName) [0x00030] in :0
>
> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory (System.String providerString) [0x00000] in <8e55e1ac4ad54cdaa461a0d3773ea935>:0
>
> Version Information: 5.12.0.233 (tarball Tue May 8 09:28:02 UTC 2018); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000

**my web.config is below:**

```html
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

```html
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="sunplotwebEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Sunplotdata.csdl|res://*/Models.Sunplotdata.ssdl|res://*/Models.Sunplotdata.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=sdDS;Password=sdDataSystem_zgf;database=sunplotweb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   
  </connectionStrings>
```

```html
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

What should i do to get it work fun?thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the first stable version of .NET production is .NET Core. It is a multiplatform Microsoft technology. So if you want to run asp.net on centOS or Linux production: try this